# AWS Lambda Authorizer not allowing application/zip response after successful authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, response-headers, lambda-authorizer

I have an GET API created which uses nodejs lambda to return a zip file with base64 encoding and content-type - application/zip. And it is working fine by downloading zip file while hitting from browser or postman when it doesn't configured with any authorizer.

[image]

But when I add an authorizer to this API, I am not able to see this zip file downloaded instead getting as json response where the response header sets content-type to "application/json".

```
{
   "statusCode":200,
   "isBase64Encoded":true,
   "body":"UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==",
   "headers":{
      "Content-Type":"application/zip, application/octet-stream",
      "Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename=Testfile.zip",
      "Content-Encoding":"base64"
   }
}
```

How to get the result in the same way i.e. getting zip file downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the api integration type to lambda-proxy instead of lambda.
This solved my issue and able to download the binary file.